# Grant service start / stop permissions to existing service using WiX

Tags: windows, service, installation, wix, windows-installer

My WiX installer installs ServiceA which runs as NetworkService. During its run time, ServiceA has an occassional need to restart an already installed ServiceB. However, ServiceB does not grant NetworkService permissions to start / stop it. 
Is there a way I can grant these permissions to NetworkService for the already installed ServiceB in my WiX installer? Can ServiceInstall and PermissionEx be used for existing services?